# javafx CategoryAxis Color single Category

Tags: css, javafx, charts, axis, textcolor

I'm using ScatterChart with CategoryAxis in JavaFX8 witht the following Categories("least", "low", "default", "high", "highes")

This works. However, I want to add a color to the "default" Category-name on the CategoryAxis to let the user know that this Category-Name is the default. So the letters "default" shall become RED on the Axis while the others shall remain grey.

Using CSS, I can change to color of all CategoryAxis. However, I only want to change one single Categoryname of all the Category-Names on the CategoryAxis.

Unfortunately, CategoryAxis is final, so I cannot try to overwrite the drawing methods.

Does anybody has a solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CategoryAxis inherits `Axis<T>` with the type `T` set to concrete type `String`. The tick label's color is set by the final property `tickLabelFill` in class `Axis<T>` for **all** labels.

So if you want to override this behaviour, you have to write a whole new Axis implementation and of course a whole new chart, because all method references in XYChart classes goes to the original Axis class.

So simply changing the symbol color and adding an explaining text is the easier way.